# Add columns to R data.table and aggregate with userdefined function returning output as vector

Tags: r, data.table

I am new to `data.table` syntax in R.

How can i add new columns and aggregate using a user-defined function that return a vector?

Example:

Some arbitrary function returning mean and median of an input object.

```
myfunc<-function(x){ 
 vec<-c(rep(NA,2))
 vec[1]<-mean(x)
 vec[2]<-median(x)
 return(vec)
}
```

A datatable

```
DT = data.table(
 ID = c("b","b","b","a","a","c"),
 a = 1:6,
 b = 7:12,
 c = 13:18
)
```

Now, i want so summarize and get a new datatable of dimension 3x2, i.e. 3 rows for the ID and 2 columns for the mean and meadian returned from `myfunc` used on column a.

I attempted (and various variations hereof)

```
 DT[,c("avg","med")=myfunc(a),by=ID]
```

which naturally fails. Instead i want ouput similar to

```
DT[, .(avg=mean(a),med=median(a)),by=ID]

> DT[, .(avg=mean(a),med=median(a)),by=ID]
#    ID avg med
# 1:  b 2.0 2.0
# 2:  a 4.5 4.5
# 3:  c 6.0 6.0
```

Also, i would appreciate some explanation of why my ridiculous attempt doesn't work so I can avoid posting stupid questions like this in the future.

Comment: `DT[, setNames(as.list(myfunc(a)), c("avg","med")),by=ID]` or change your function to return a list.

Comment: @Roland Thank you, it works and I think I understand the logic. If you "Answer" the question I will mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data:

```
DT = data.table(
    ID = c("b","b","b","a","a","c"),
    a = 1:6,
    b = 7:12,
    c = 13:18
)
```

code:

```
myfunc<-function(x){ 
    return( data.frame(avg = as.numeric(mean(x)), med = as.numeric(median(x))) )
}

# DT[,myfunc(.SD$a), by = ID] # can be simplified
DT[,myfunc(a), by = ID]
```

result:

```
#   ID avg med
#1:  b 2.0 2.0
#2:  a 4.5 4.5
#3:  c 6.0 6.0
```

---

extension:

```
DT[,do.call(cbind, lapply(.SD, myfunc)), by = ID]  # or
# DT[,unlist(lapply(.SD, myfunc), recursive = F), by = ID]


#   ID a.avg a.med b.avg b.med c.avg c.med
#1:  b   2.0   2.0   8.0   8.0  14.0  14.0
#2:  a   4.5   4.5  10.5  10.5  16.5  16.5
#3:  c   6.0   6.0  12.0  12.0  18.0  18.0
```

Comment: Thank you for this alternative and the extension - I like the use of do.call there! Why is the data.frame used in the function instead of another data.table? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: I try to stay `base::` where I can. There is no difference using df or dt there. But on a side note you could use `myfunc` in a `base::` scenario somewhere else.